# Linq-to-Sql Read-Test-Write as one operation

Tags: linq-to-sql, database-concurrency

I have `Tasks` table: `Id (PK), TaskName, Status`
Status is one of: **Queued**, **Busy**, **Complete**.
I want to use multiple threads to process the tasks, and for that I need to be able to do in one operation:

```
var task = db.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Status == (byte) TaskStatus.Queued);
task.Status = (byte) TaskStatus.Busy;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Obviously if operation is not atomic I can get concurrency issues. What is (if one exists) an intended way to do the above using Linq-to-Sql?

I know I can do that with 1) storproc or 2) `db.ExecuteCommand("...")` or 3) handle the conflict `with try/catch` - but I want to be sure there is no a better way.

I know it is a very basic question, but I wasn't able to find a definite answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to be sure that this is happening atomically in the database (regardless of what thread or application is calling it), you probably should do it in a sproc and lock at an appropriate level there. The sproc should retrieve and update the record, then release and return it (Ack! I don't mean the TSQL `return` statement, but you know I mean `select` it, I trust!)

So L2S just calls the sproc and gets back a task to work on, already set as `Busy`. L2S neither knows (nor cares) what/how things were locked - and therefore can not complicate matters and introduce more chances for deadlocks.